# How can I limit the length of the symbols in an input tag?

Tags: html, handlebars.js

I have this code in my Handlebars template.

```
<div class="form-item-body {{name}}">
    <input type="text" class="form-textbox" name="{{name}}" id="{{name}}" value="{{value}}">
</div>
```

How can I limit the length of the symbols in my input tag?

Comment: are you asking how to limit the number of characters on your input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use maxlength attribute for it..

for eg

```
<input type="text" class="form-textbox" maxlength="25" name="{{name}}" id="{{name}}" value="{{value}}">
```

Here [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/dZMLb/)

Answer (score 0):

use  property maxlength, example:

```
maxlength="10"
```

also see [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp)